# PHP page load Random Image on Startup

Tags: php, image, random

I would like to open a web page that simply contains one of three images.  I want a random image to open up at any given time.    My code is not working.  This is what I have:

```
 <?php
 $imageArray = array(
 1 => array("address" => "Daily_Deals_Updated1.png", "alt_text" => "Image 1"),
 2 => array("address" => "Daily_Deals_Updated2.png", "alt_text" => "Image 2"),
 3 => array("address" => "Daily_Deals_Updated3.png", "alt_text" => "Image 3"),
 );
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Daily Deals</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="margin: 100px auto 0; width: 454px;">
        <?php
        $randomImageNumber = array_rand($imageArray, 1);
        echo "<img src='" . $imageArray[$randomImageNumber]['address']' . " />";
        ?>

        <!--        <img src="Daily Deals_Updated.png" alt="Daily Deals!" /> -->
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

After this is successful, I would like to change the randomness a bit where the images only show up a certain percentage of the time.  For example, 1 image 45%, 1 image 45% 1 image 10%.

There is nothing else on the web page but ONE image.  I would like to keep it all on one script where I do not have to include other files.

Edit:  Code that works!

```
 <?php
      $images=array(0=>'Daily_Deals_Updated.png',1=>'Daily_Deals_Updated2.png',2=>'Daily_Deals_Updated.png',);
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Daily Deals</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="margin: 100px auto 0; width: 454px;">
        <?php
            $r = rand(0, 100) / 100;

        if ($r < 0.75) {
            $output="<img src=\"Demonstration_Screen_1.png\" >";
            print($output);
        } else if ($r > 0.76 && $r < 0.94) {
            $output="<img src=\"Demonstration_Screen_2.png\" >";
                print($output);
        } else if ($r > 0.95)  {
            $output="<img src=\"Demonstration_Screen_3.png\" >";
            print($output);
        }
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a random number `r` between 0 and 1, then follow the pseudocode below.

```
if (r < 0.45)
    display first image
else if (r < .9)
    display second image
else
    display third image
```

This can be extended to any number of cases and any probabilities for each. Notice the first one is from `[0, 0.45)`, the second from `[0.45, 0.9)`, and the third is `[0.9, 1.0]`. You just need to split the interval in a way that suits your needs and can have as many if/elseif cases.

Comment: FYI, to get a random number between 0 and 1: `rand(0, 100) / 100;`

Comment: In good coding habits, the second should be else if (r > 0.45 && r < 0.9)

Comment: @MichaelH, not sure if this is the right place to ask but can you briefly explain why that is considered good practice (or why not doing it may be considered bad practice)? Is it just so it's more clear when reading the code?

Comment: I imagine it's just because it's easier to read what the conditions are to enter that `if` without having to find the previous `if` statement (which may be many many lines away). Not sure if I agree with the habit although I don't disagree with it.

Comment: Yeah really it's the clarity of the code. It can save a heap of time when looking back for errors or when someone else is reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Name the images something like img1,img2,img3 etc.

Then use

```
$img=rand(0,3);
$bg="img$img";
```